# Save the results of a mixed model in a dataset

Tags: stata, mixed

I am fitting the mixed model below:

```
. mixed y trt || clst:trt, nocons reml dfmethod(sat)

Performing EM optimization: 

Performing gradient-based optimization: 

Iteration 0:   log restricted-likelihood = -1295.3123  
Iteration 1:   log restricted-likelihood = -1295.3098  
Iteration 2:   log restricted-likelihood = -1295.3098  

Computing standard errors:

Computing degrees of freedom:

Mixed-effects REML regression                   Number of obs     =        919
Group variable: clst                            Number of groups  =         49

                                                Obs per group:
                                                              min =          1
                                                              avg =       18.8
                                                              max =         30
DF method: Satterthwaite                        DF:           min =     888.00
                                                              avg =     900.91
                                                              max =     913.83

                                                F(1,   913.83)    =       0.40
Log restricted-likelihood = -1295.3098          Prob > F          =     0.5251

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         trt |   .1455914   .2290005     0.64   0.525    -.3038366    .5950193
       _cons |   .3951269   .2241477     1.76   0.078    -.0447941     .835048
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Random-effects Parameters  |   Estimate   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
clst: Identity               |
                    var(trt) |   .0341507   .0173905      .0125877     .092652
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
               var(Residual) |   .9546016   .0453034      .8698131    1.047655
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LR test vs. linear model: chibar2(01) = 9.46          Prob >= chibar2 = 0.0010

. return list

scalars:
              r(level) =  95

matrices:
              r(table) :  9 x 4
```

Next, I calculate the `ICC` as follows:

```
. nlcom (icc_est: (exp(_b[lns1_1_1:_cons])^2)/((exp(_b[lns1_1_1:_cons])^2)+(exp(_b[lnsig_e:_cons])^2)))

     icc_est:  (exp(_b[lns1_1_1:_cons])^2)/((exp(_b[lns1_1_1:_cons])^2)+(exp(_b[lnsig_e:_cons])^2))

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     icc_est |   .0345392   .0171907     2.01   0.045     .0008461    .0682323
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I save the results in the dataset?

I want to keep all the three tables shown: fixed effects, random effects and the ICC results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following reproducible example using Stata's `pig` toy dataset:

```
webuse pig, clear

mixed weight week || id:week, nocons reml dfmethod(sat)

nlcom (icc_est: (exp(_b[lns1_1_1:_cons])^2)/((exp(_b[lns1_1_1:_cons])^2)+(exp(_b[lnsig_e:_cons])^2))), post

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     icc_est |   .1380299   .0265754     5.19   0.000     .0859431    .1901167
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The following works for me:

```
generate double coef = _b[icc_est]
generate double se = _se[icc_est]

generate p = string(2 * (normal(-(_b[icc_est] / _se[icc_est]))), "%9.3f")

generate double upper = _b[icc_est] + _se[icc_est] * invnormal(0.025)
generate double lower = _b[icc_est] + _se[icc_est] * invnormal(0.975)

list coef se p upper lower in 1 

     +-------------------------------------------------------+
     |      coef          se       p       upper       lower |
     |-------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | .13802987   .02657538   0.000   .08594308   .19011667 |
     +-------------------------------------------------------+

save mydata.dta
```

The process is similar for the results of the main model.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up, getting the random intercept variance and SE and residual variance and SE easily will take one more line of code.  But as the previous reply indicated, the results from the main model are obtained in the same way as the ICC results.  See code below.

```
mixed y trt || clst:trt, nocons reml dfmethod(sat)
gen double fixedcoef = _b[trt]
gen double fixedse = _se[trt]

_diparm lns1_1_1, f(exp(@)^2) d(2*exp(@)^2)
gen double randomcoef = r(est)
gen double randomse = r(se)

_diparm lnsig_e, f(exp(@)^2) d(2*exp(@)^2)
gen double residcoef = r(est)
gen double residse = r(se)
```

Comment: These can also be calculated directly from the returned results.